# How to use condition in laravel query

Tags: laravel

Hello I am new to laravel. I am getting an error saying  'Property [pickupdate] does not exist on this collection instance.', after fowarding to 'overdue_pickup' view.

My Controller code

```
    public function overdue_pickup(){
        $id = "2";
        $curr_date = date('m/d/yy');
        $overdue_pickup = DB::table('archive_pickup')
        ->where('ridder_id_',$id)
        ->get();


        if($overdue_pickup->pickupdate < $curr_date){
          return view('overdue_pickup',['overdue_pickup' => 
        $overdue_pickup]);
   
        }else{
            return "No Overdue Pickup";
        }
    }


 My overdue_pickup view


  <?php $i = 1; ?>
      @foreach($overdue_pickup as $overdue_pickup)
      <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
    <div class="box box-success">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title" style="padding:5px">Order No: <b><?php echo $i;?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$overdue_pickup->status}}</b></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
          <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
               <p><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Pickup Time:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; {{$overdue_pickup->pickuptime}}</p>
               <p><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Delivery Time:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; {{$overdue_pickup->deliverytime}}</p>
              
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
       @endforeach
```

Comment: Liam, please show the code/sample data of the `DB::table('archive_pickup')` The issue is this line of code: `if($overdue_pickup->pickupdate < $curr_date){` The error is saying that whatever object `$overdue_pickup = DB::table('archive_pickup')` is, does not have the property `pickupdate`   - You can probably do a `var_dump($overdue_pickup)` and past the result here if it isn't obvious what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that your record for `$id=2` is one,
Change

```
$assign_pickup = DB::table('archive_pickup')
        ->where('ridder_id',$id)
        ->get();
```

to first()

```
$assign_pickup = DB::table('archive_pickup')
        ->where('ridder_id',$id)
        ->first();
```

Then use

```
if($assign_pickup->pickdate > $curr_date){
    return view('Ridder.assign',['assigned_pickup' => $assigned_pickup]);
}else{
    return "No Overdue Pickup";
}
```

If not one then use foreach & no need to change get() statement,

```
foreach($assign_pickup as $assign_pick){
    if($assign_pick->pickdate > $curr_date){
        // ... your logic
}else{
        // ..your logic
}
}
```

EDIT:

```
public function overdue_pickup(){
        $id = "2";
        $curr_date = date('m/d/yy');
        $overdue_pickup = DB::table('archive_pickup')
        ->where('ridder_id_',$id)
        ->get();

        return view('overdue_pickup',['overdue_pickup' => 
        $overdue_pickup]);
    }
```

In your view, you can just foreach loop through it,

```
@foreach($overdue_pickup as $overdue_pick)
    @if($overdue_pick->pickdate > $curr_date)
    {{-- show your view --}}
    @else
    <p class="text-warning">No Overdue Pickup</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the record am retrieving for $id=2 is not one, what am i to change from my query

Comment: I have updated for multiple, but you are using return statement it will return the function call after once only.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate

Comment: What should i use instead of the return statement?

Comment: can you please tell what you want to do in detail or update the question to specify your goal then we can help you out easily.

Comment: can you give some example how your data is in there in `$overdue_pickup` from the query `DB::table`

Comment: you can use `dd($overdue_pickup);` to see what you are recieving from the query(statement at 3rd line), just add this in the 4th line

Comment: I have edited the answer you can use if statements in the view itself, as once you will use  return it will return the statement